# Tagging opening questions using a naming convention that avoids clashes with tags for players

Tags: discussion, tags

Recently, I [edited a question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/posts/31952/revisions) to replace the tags [from](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/from) and [lisitsin](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lisitsin) with [froms-gambit](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/froms-gambit) and [lisitsin-gambit](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lisitsin-gambit), respectively, in order to avoid future name clashes should anyone later ask questions about either Martin Severin From or Georgy Lisitsin (or both), since tags for players also use just the family name. However, when I wanted to do something similar for [grob](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grob) I noticed that [this question had been revised](https://chess.stackexchange.com/posts/31952/revisions) to remove the tag [grob-opening](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grob-opening) and only leave the tag [grob](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grob). (The question is about the opening, not about Henri Grob.)

Can we establish a tagging policy for openings and players that avoids future name clashes between players and openings named after them? I see two potential policies that would consistently avoid name clashes:

1. Always add a noun such as "opening", "gambit" or "defence" to a tag for an opening named after a player.
   Continue using family names for tags for players.
2. Don't add nouns such as "opening", "gambit" or "defence" to tags for openings named after players.
   Combine first name and family name for tags for players.

If neither of these seems feasible or acceptable (I have not yet checked how many tags the site has for players versus tags for openings), how will consistency in tagging openings be ensured?

Comment: I have stopped editing tag wiki excerpts because of the inconsistency in tags for openings.

Comment: wish i could set a bounty on a meta post...