# Should we create tags named after chess players?

Tags: discussion, tags

We've got plenty of tags named after chess players (famous and not):

- [fischer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fischer)
- [tal](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tal)
- [kasparov](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kasparov)
- [karpov](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/karpov)
- [alekhine](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alekhine)
- [carlsen](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/carlsen)
- [nakamura](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nakamura)
- [nepomniachtchi](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nepomniachtchi)
- [ding](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ding)
- [anand](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anand)
- [aronian](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aronian)
- [kramnik](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kramnik)
- [jovanka-houska](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jovanka-houska)

Most of them have only 1-2 questions! While I understand that some of these chess players are probably the greatest of all times (thus creating a tag dedicated to them seems reasonable) the rest are either not famous or haven't really affected the history of chess.

Are those tags acceptable? When should they be created?

Comment: I've been wondering the same thing recently. Ripe for Meta discussion.

Comment: Have you noticed that the tags for openings named after players can cause clashes with names of players? See [Tagging opening questions using a naming convention that avoids clashes with tags for players](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/883/10867).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am against the usage of tags named after chess players. This does not help to define the question, nor does it help in the search. If the player's name is relevant to the question, it would have been used in the question body anyway; thus, being searchable.

In particular, I think that using a *chess-player tag* is harmful when tagging a question that only contains a game involving a certain chess player.

Moreover, the practice of using such tags unnecessarily complicates the "tag cloud" and makes the organization harder.

Answer (score -1):

I think only for very commonly asked about players (like Magnus Carlsen). Look at these tags. If they have more than 10 or 25 questions, keep them. Otherwise, goodbye.

Answer (score -6):

Re

> If the player's name is relevant to the question, it would have been used in the question body anyway; thus, being searchable.

I think player name tags are helpful for those 'watch tag' things.

Then again I suppose you could always bookmark a search for the name and check it everyday if you want. But then in that case, why don't you do the same for other tags like, say, [chess960](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess960)?

Anyhoo that's just my vote.